# Remove HTML code from content printed by wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am printing out the content of a specific post (103 in this case) with the following code:

```
<?php $post_id = 103; $queried_post = get_post($post_id); echo apply_filters('the_content',$queried_post->post_content); ?>
```

How can I make it exclude all the html tags like `<p>` and `<br>s`, and just show the text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use strip_tag(string) function to remove all html tags from string

```
echo strip_tags(apply_filters('the_content',$queried_post->post_content));
```

Comment: great that seems to work how can I do the same for <?php the_excerpt(); ?> ? Thanks!

Comment: instead of the_excerpt(), use strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()), strip_tags won't work at the_excerpt